# Post Route from Footer NODE JS/EXPRESS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

So I am building a website that is essentially a blog. I have posts routes from multiple pages that link to a DB.

Q: How can I get I guess multiple posts route to work on one path / how can I program the 1 post route to do 'either or' ?

Hope my question is clear,

Thanks

The issue is I have a "subsribe to email" form in the footer at the moment that displays on all pages. I can get the post route to work however it cancels out any of the other post routes that are on that same path.
For ex: 
1. I have a post route for new blog posts on /blog
2. if i enter an email address in the form from the footer and submit the current post route will work (send me an email to that a new subscriber has been added) however if i now go to try and add a new blog post it will just submit a post request of the empty form from the footer and send me an email with 'undefined" (obv).

```
//CREATE - add new blogpost to DB
router.post("/blog", function(req, res){

  var name = req.body.name;
  var image = req.body.image;
  var desc = req.body.description;
  var author = {
      id: req.user._id,
      username: req.user.username
  }
  var email = req.body.email;

  geocoder.geocode(req.body.location, function (err, data) {
    if (err || !data.length) {
      req.flash('error', 'Invalid Address');
      return res.redirect('back');
    }
    var lat = data[0].latitude;
    var lng = data[0].longitude;
    var location = data[0].formattedAddress;
    var newPost = {name: name, image: image, caption: caption, description: desc, author:author, location: location, lat: lat, lng: lng};
    // Create a new Post and save to DB
    Post.create(newPost, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //redirect back to posts page
           console.log(newlyCreated);
            res.redirect("/blog");
        }
    });
  });
});

________________________________


router.post("/blog", (req,res) => {
     const output = `
             <p> You have a new subscriber </p>
             <h3> Contact Details </h3>
            <ul>
            <li> Email: ${req.body.email} </li>
             </ul>
            <h3> Message </h3>
            <p>  Someone Subscribed to your email list </p>
    `;
          let mailerConfig = {    
             host: "smtp.office365.com",  
             secureConnection: true,
            port: 587,
            auth: {
               user: "####",
                pass: "###"
             }
        };
         let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailerConfig);

        let mailOptions = {
             from: mailerConfig.auth.user,
             to: '@',  
             subject: 'Someone subscribed to your Blog!',
             html: output
         };

         transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error) {
             if (error) {
                 console.log('error:', error);
             } else {
                 console.log('message sent');
                 req.flash("success","Message Sent!")
                 res.redirect("back");

             }
         });
 });
```

---

How can I get these two to work together so when someone enters their email address and submits the form (on any of the pages in the website) it will submit the data without potentially interupting any other post routes on the current page.

Comment: Just handle it in one uniq route. Attach a name to the submit. And check if the name appears in the body.... Or, as you have an email name field, just check is presence or not...